# How does SQL's LIKE work in case of Path Enumeration?

Tags: sql, sql-like

I am reading the book [SQL Antipatterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356557) where a SQL query is used like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Comments AS c
WHERE '1/4/6/7/' LIKE c.path || '%';
```

to find ancestors of comment #7 from this table:

[image]

I am not much familiar with the regex employed for LIKE and would appreciate understanding how it does its work.  Specifically, does it matter that the literal **'1/4/6/7'** is located on the left hand of the LIKE keyword? And how does the entire WHERE predicate work (i.e. **|| '%'**)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, in case it is not clear, the `||` is the string concatenation operator.  So, if the value of `c.path` is `'1/'`, then `c.path || '%'` yields `'1/%'`.

So, obviously, you cannot do `WHERE field LIKE 'constant%'` because in this particular (weird) kind of query it is the constant that may be longer than the field, and not the other way around.

Usually, what we do with `LIKE` is `WHERE field LIKE 'constant%'` to check whether the value of the field starts with the constant.  Here the author of the query wants to see whether the constant starts with the value of the field, which is a bizarre thing to do.

Comment: That's it, I thought the || was an OR.  Thank you soooo much.

Comment: Putting the second part in parentheses would have been so much more readable, like so: WHERE '1/4/6/7/' LIKE **(c.path || '%')**;

Answer (score 1):

Simple `LIKE` expression in SQL (as opposed to [regex `LIKE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm), available in some RDBMS) does not support regular expressions. Instead, it supports two special "wildcard" characters: underscore `_` that is roughly equivalent to dot `.` in regex, and percent `%` which is roughly equivalent to `.*` construct.

`||` in the example is concatenation operator, similar to operator `+` applied to `String` objects in Java. Hence, a constant value `1/4/6/7/` is compared to a string from the `path` column followed by any characters - essentially, a prefix match.

This is a bad approach, because it places data from the table on the right side of the `LIKE` expression. This is very expensive, because this operation cannot use indexing, making the search run very slowly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, especially the third paragraph re: performance.  Coming from a programming background, the || operator really disoriented me.